# TCL threads not running simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I am working on a task, which must be solved in TCL. Because this task involves communication with several IO devices in parallel, I thought to solve it with threads. Because I observed problems, I wrote this TCL script, to test the threading behavior:

```
package require Thread

set t1 [thread::create {
    for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
        puts "AAA $i"
        after 50
    }
}]
puts "Created thread t1"

set t2 [thread::create {
    for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
        puts "BBB $i"
        after 50
    }
}]
puts "Created thread t2"

# ---------------------------
after 1000

proc threadprocSync {msg n} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
        puts "$msg $i"
        after 50
    }
}

set t3 [thread::create [threadprocSync "CCC" 10]]
puts "Created thread t3"

set t4 [thread::create [threadprocSync "DDD" 10]]
puts "Created thread t4"

# ---------------------------
after 1000

proc outproc {msg i} {
    puts "$msg $i"
}

proc threadprocAsync {t msg n} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
        thread::send -async $t [outproc $msg $i]
        after 50
    }
}

set tWorker [thread::create -preserved]
puts "Created thread tWorker"

# ---------------------------

set t5 [thread::create [threadprocAsync $tWorker "EEE" 10]]
puts "Created thread t5"

set t6 [thread::create [threadprocAsync $tWorker "FFF" 10]]
puts "Created thread t6"

# ---------------------------
after 1000
thread::release $tWorker
```

The code contains delays of 50 ms to make the execution slower, so that the threads needs significantly more time, than the initialization of the environment. But I observe here, that only the first pair of threads, which print AAA and BBB runs simultaneously. I expected the same behavior also for the threads with CCC and DDD and for the threads with EEE and FFF. What am I doing wrong?

The above script produces the following output:

```
C:\Projects\tcltest>tclsh threads.tcl
Created thread t1
AAA 0
Created thread t2
BBB 0
AAA 1
BBB 1
AAA 2
BBB 2
AAA 3
BBB 3
BBB 4
AAA 4
AAA 5
BBB 5
AAA 6
BBB 6
BBB 7
AAA 7
AAA 8
BBB 8
AAA 9
BBB 9
CCC 0
CCC 1
CCC 2
CCC 3
CCC 4
CCC 5
CCC 6
CCC 7
CCC 8
CCC 9
Created thread t3
DDD 0
DDD 1
DDD 2
DDD 3
DDD 4
DDD 5
DDD 6
DDD 7
DDD 8
DDD 9
Created thread t4
Created thread tWorker
EEE 0
EEE 1
EEE 2
EEE 3
EEE 4
EEE 5
EEE 6
EEE 7
EEE 8
EEE 9
Created thread t5
FFF 0
FFF 1
FFF 2
FFF 3
FFF 4
FFF 5
FFF 6
FFF 7
FFF 8
FFF 9
Created thread t6

C:\Projects\tcltest>
```

Comment: How many CPU cores are available on the hardware where you're running? If there's only two (effectively, after allowing for everything else that's going on on the system) then you are only ever going to actually run at most two things simultaneously, and the others will wait until the OS decides to give them priority.

Comment: You are not running CCC, DDD, EEE, and FFF in the threads you created. You are running `threadprocSync`, `threadprocAsync`, and `outproc` in the main thread, and then sending their results as the script to the threads. But the result of all those procedures is "". So your threads are not doing anything.